# How do I automatically run a shell script at start up?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Situation: Whenever I boot up my Raspberry PI, I have to enter a few lines of commands to enable an interface. The commands:

```
sudo modprobe batman-adv
sudo batctl if add wlan0
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo ifconfig bat0 up
```

I would like to run a script that allows these commands to execute automatically when I boot up the Raspberry PI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add those commands to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Do you mean `/etc/init.d/rc.local`?

Comment: You can use both , but  the purpose of `/etc/rc.local` is to provide a place to put shell commands to run at boot without having to deal with the stop|start service stuff, which is in `/etc/init.d/rc.local`.

Comment: Yes I want to create a shell which includes the above commands. Once that is done, do I need to put the script file in /etc/init.d/rc.local?

Comment: You don't have to make a script , just add the commands in the end of the file before `exit 0`